# How to get privileges to use Index, by giving grants to tables will have by default grant for using index..?

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have created new user and given select, update, delete, insert grants on all table for new user, my question is whether I can use indexes with out giving any grant on index for the existing tables.

Note:- I don't want to create new index, I want use existing indexes which is already created by admin.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are the (optional) structure associated with table. You don't need to grant anything to an index, Oracle handles it internally.

If you have the privilege to select the table, then while querying the table optimizer will use the required index(if any). Optimizer won't stop you form anything related to an index.

Why don't you test it yourself?

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR query;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

In the execution plan, see whether  the index is being used or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are no explicit grants available for indexes. If you have access to the table you can use the indexes.

But using the indexes i usually not done explicitly - it is taken care of by the optimizer behind the scenes.